# Spreadsheet autofill increase in middle of text (Lotus 123 could, Excel cannot?)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I could drag a series in Lotus 123 (25 years ago!) and it was intuitive about what should increase. For example:

```
xyz1abc
xyz2abc
```

Would drag to:

```
xyz3abc
xyz4abc
```

Etc.

Excel seems to be able to manage an increase only on the end of a string. Lotus could also increase letters in a series and I haven't found a way to get Excel to do that either!

Any ideas?

1234A
1234B
would drag to
1234C
1234D 
in Lotus. Excel just repeats the first two cells like an idiot - at least as far as I've been able to find. Is there a way to turn on this function in Excel?

Comment: Excel 2013 handles your first example with Flash Fill, but I couldn't get letters to increment.

Answer (score -1):

You could use custom formatting on the cells in format "xyz"#"abc" and only write the number 1 in the first cell and then just drag to increment the next cells holding CTRL.

Here is a screenshot:

[[image: screenshot]]